# how I can call global command function in phpstorm without calling a programs?

Tags: compiler-construction, coffeescript, phpstorm

I have installed coffee-script globally using nodejs. I can call

"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\New folder>coffee -wc "C:\portables\xampp-portable
\htdocs\test" to compile all cofee-script file in my test folder.

now I have a problem with phpstorm.

I have given my phpstorm settings as below.

```
parameters =  coffee -wc "$FileDir$"
```

It has not worked. I think it requires the program to call the file. I have tried to give my file name as programs..

It giving an error that test.coffeescript is not valid win32 apps.

[image]

check that I also tried to call nodejs exe but it has not worked.My own system node functionality calling "coffee -wc "C:\portables\xampp-portable
\htdocs\test"" is working on my system.

How can I call it in phpstorm. The difference is in phpstorm. How I can call same cmd function without calling any programs as I have called in my cmd.

Answer (score 2):

`coffee` is actually a `coffee.cmd` file on Windows. Did you try to use `c:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` as the **Program** and then provide full path to the `coffee.cmd` and the rest of the options in the **Parameters**?

The follwing works for me:

[image: coffee tool]

Output in the console:

```
c:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C c:\Users\Serge\AppData\Roaming\npm\coffee.cmd -wc D:\work\attaches\nodesample
15:26:47 - compiled D:\work\attaches\nodesample\sample.coffee
```